# How to see missing translation errors in Android Studio 3?

Tags: android-studio

When I build a project with Android Studio 3.0.1, missing translations are not visible i.e. if a string is in values/strings.xml but not in values-fr/strings.xml, no error is thrown.

Can Android Studio throw an error when building the project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I've found a solution using lint.

Add this to your module or app's gradle file:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError true
}
```

then build the project and check the file app\build\reports\lint-results.html for missing translations